# Несколько рабочих столов на Windows 7

Tags: windows

Какое решение для Windows лучше всего сможет передать комфорт от использования нескольких рабочих столов (multidesktop)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) - попробуйте :-)

Comment: Не плохо. Есть почти весь нужный функционал(используя модули), но жутко не хватает анимации.

Comment: А перейти на линукс для вас трудно? Если все-таки нужна Windows можно попробовать VirtualBox, меня вполне устраивает такой вариант. Т.е. у меня стоит ubuntu на ней стоит virtual box с windows xp.

Comment: Перепробовал несколько вариантов, этот оказался самым стоящим. Спасибо.

Comment: а я поставил linux дома и рад очень-очень)

Answer (score 2):

у Марка Руссиновича есть прекрасная утилита - [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881). На моей Windows Seven прекрасно работает. Всего 60 кб.

Comment: Мне понравилось

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю нужен аналог компиза(с его кубом) из иксов?

Comment: Ну компиз это будет уже излишество. Я хочу разделить два вида работы на два рабочих стола. Второй монитор занят отображением статистики.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько мониторов :) Это даже лучше ;) Рекоммендую один 22, а второй хотя бы 17 дюймов. Я в такой конфигурации работаю и просто нарадоваться не могу.

Comment: У меня 22" и 19", но на меньшом всегда должна быть видна статистическая информация.

Comment: 24 + 15.6 (ноут все-таки).

Answer (score 1):

Я пользовался DeskSpace, очень удобная вещь.